# Why doesn't this code return the full document height?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The following code *should* return the full height of the document, but it does not. It says the height is `1023` but (measuring by screenshots and scrolling and photoshop) the actual height is `1804`. Why is it wrong? How do I get the full height?

```
var height = Math.max( 
    document.body.scrollHeight,
    document.body.offsetHeight,
    document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
    document.body.clientHeight,
    document.documentElement.clientHeight
);
```

**EDIT I was not clear. I want *document* height, not *window* height. By "screenshots and scrolling and photoshop", I meant I did the following:**

1. Took a screenshot and copied the window height and put in a new image
2. Scrolled a full window height again and took a new screenshot and pasted that onto #1
3. Continued until I couldn't scroll anymore and pasted in the remaining height

That gave me **document** height.

Comment: The height of the **document** is not necessarily the height of the browser window it's in.

Comment: Was the browser zoomed in when you took those screenshots? That would cause your results to disagree with the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your page to occupy the full height of the browser window, you can add this CSS rule:

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

That tells the browser that the body should be at least as big as the viewport. Things like that work best when you've imposed `border-box` box sizing on everything:

```
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body *, body *:before, body *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

That way padding and borders won't cause unwanted unnecessary scroll bars.

Answer (score 0):

What about window.innerHeight; ? That sounds like what you would be measuring in a screenshot of the browser window.

Comment: I want document height. I took a screenshot, scrolled, took another and continued until I went through the whole page. Then I pasted them together to get the full height. I want document height.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between document and window height.
It looks like you are trying to get the window height.
Try using `window.innerHeight` instead or the document heights. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you did a mistake while copy-pasting your screens.

I just made my own tests using following script to be sure I was scrolling one page height at a time :

```
window.onclick = function(){
        document.documentElement.scrollTop += window.innerHeight;
        }
```

Results show that your function give the same height as what copy-pasting each window does.

However, as [goldfire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1508094/goldfire) pointed out, if you were zooming in your page, result might be different.

Comment: I did not. I created an overlay div and set it to that height and it does not go the full height. And `jQuery( document ).height()` is larger.

Answer (score 0):

The `document` itself has no height. You can only get the height of the `documentElement`, which is the representation of the document. All following approaches gives the same result:

```
var h0 = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
var h1 = document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().height;
var h2 = $(document).height();
```

See [working Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yj2jnahg/24/).
I have tried your method with a screenshot in the following way: I opend a document much higher than the screen in Firefox, catched the whole page with FireShot (its possible without scrolling) and saved it as an image. Its pixel-height was exactly the same as what I got with h0, h1, h2 above.